# DC.js xAxis range, show only a subset

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

In the following example, what would be the best way to adjust the xAxis to only show from 2 - max for the "Number of Events by Magnitude"?

[dc.js chart example, New Zealand Earthquakes](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6584483)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer expands on @Gerardo's solution, making the chart adjust dynamically, and dealing with a few dc.js quirks.

First, the original author of this example fudged a few things just to get stuff working. If you want truly dynamic axes, you'll need to show dc.js how to calculate the bar widths for itself:

```
magnitudeChart
  .xUnits(dc.units.fp.precision(0.1))
```

and remove `.gap(65)` - that kind of magic number is always a sign that someone couldn't figure out how to get things calculated automatically.

There are a few quirks with how dc.js deals with bar charts. For one, it doesn't really account for its own bar width or centering when it sets the domain - it uses exactly what you give it. You'll notice that the rightmost bar is missing when automatically calculating the maximum. (This happens with `elasticX(true)` too.)

So let's turn off bar-centering and add the 0.1 bar width to the domain each time we calculate it.

```
magnitudeChart
  .centerBar(false)
  .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([2, d3.max(data, d=>d.mag)+0.1]))
```

Next, crossfilter does not automatically remove empty bins, so we can wrap the group in a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) to do that:

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value != 0;
            });
        }
    };
}

magnitudeChart
  .group(remove_empty_bins(magValueGroupCount))
```

And we can have the chart recalculate its domain every time it's redrawn like so:

```
.on('preRedraw', function(chart) {
  chart.x().domain([2, d3.max(chart.group().all(), kv=>kv.key) + 0.1]);
  chart.rescale();
});
```

Fork of the block: http://bl.ocks.org/gordonwoodhull/7675bb4bb67354cfdc7c6841106d7b31

Comment: Great dissection of an example.  This will help a lot.

Comment: Excellent explanation. You are the creator of dc, right?

Comment: Nope, I've just maintained it for a few years. I think I learn more from answering questions than I do from coding, although I enjoy both activities. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0.5, 7.5]))
```

To:

```
.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([2, d3.max(data, d=>d.mag)]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  This pointed me in the right direction.  I hadn't thought through if I wanted ordinal or linear x scale.  Looking back at my data, I actually wanted ordinal.